# Лишний знак = в php коде

Tags: php, html

Писал код на php, сделал форму обычную, но при выводе в браузере, пишет что на 26 строчке кода лишний знак =... все проверил, никакой ошибки быть не должно. я новичок и может что-то не понимаю, помогите пж.
Вот 25-27 строчки кода:

```
<label> От кого: </label><br />
<input type = "text" name = "from" value = "<? = $from ?>" /><br />
<label> Кому: </label><br />
```

Ошибка:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in ... on line 26

Comment: пробелы вокруг = уберите

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего лишний пробел перед знаком `=`:

`<?= $from ?>`

`<?=` это короткая запись `<?php echo`

Answer (score 2):

`<?=` это, так называемый, короткий тег для вывода информации, от сокращает запись `<? echo`

Синтаксис языка требует , что бы между знаками ? и = не было никаких других символов, т.ч. пробелов.

Т.е. правильная запись выглядит так: `<?= $from ?>` (остальные пробелы в этой записи так же можно убрать, они необязательные)

```
<input type="text" name="from" value="<?=$from?>"/><br />
```

Подробнее можно прочитать тут: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php

Answer (score 0):

ну такого синтаксиса в языке нет: `"<? = $from ?>"` напишите просто `"<? echo $from ?>"`
Но если Вы хотите вывести в сокращённом синтаксисе, то вывод должен выглядеть так: `<?=$from?>`

Comment: Помогла идея с ```echo```. Но появился вопрос, разве играют роль пробелы? Или вы имеете ввиду то, что меньше кнопок нажимать надо, чтобы сократить время?

Comment: @intskull Пробелы у равно играют роль) я пользуюсь всегда `echo` и проблем никогда нет, если у Вас к тому же старая версия языка, то чтобы использовать равно надо включать директиву конфигурации short_open_tag. Поэтому используйте echo и радуйтесь жизни)

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<input type = "text" name = "from" value = '.$from.' /><br />';
```